# Adding a variable in fieldname call?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to enable some disabled fields in my html page that have a count for example :

```
<input type="text" name="company_<?php echo $j; ?>"size="10" disabled="disabled">
```

where `$j` is a counter variable... so I need to do something like this in JavaScript part to enable these fields:

```
document.form1.company_"VARIABLE".disabled=false;
```

So is it even possible to add a Variable value in such a place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByName("company_" + yourVariable)[0].disabled = false;
```

I think this is what you are looking for